# Ag grid material theme row and header height not working

Tags: angular-material2, ag-grid, ag-grid-ng2

As suggested in documentation, i have tried below properties first.

```
this.gridOptions.rowHeight = 25;  
this.gridOptions.headerHeight= 28;
```

But it ended up like below:
[grid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gwJSG.jpg)

We have also tried the material css property changes, but didnt see any reflection to the grid.

```
$ag-mat-grid-size: 4px;
$ag-mat-icon-size: 12px;
```

Please give us the suggestion here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try providing those properties at the grid itself.

```
 <ag-grid-angular 
       [gridOptions]="myGridOptions"
       [rowHeight]="25"          //or [rowHeight]="hightParam"
       [headerHeight]="28"       //or [headerHeight]="headerHeightParam"
  >
 </ag-grid-angular>
```

I have checked it and it works.

That's why I find [ag-grid](/questions/tagged/ag-grid) kind of strange sometimes. Many of the properties they show under `gridOptions` under documentation, but they works only when we apply at the grid level itself. Although its performance compensates this behaviour `:)`

Check this working example plunk link **[ag-grid material theme example](https://plnkr.co/edit/oxFtPxWOyqAlChUIn1mT?p=preview)**

Comment: well it works for me, can you reproduce your issue in  https://plnkr.co/edit/ or  https://stackblitz.com ?

Comment: @Harshavardhan **[ag-grid material theme example](https://plnkr.co/edit/oxFtPxWOyqAlChUIn1mT?p=preview)**

Comment: @Harshavardhan if you think this helped you, you can upvote it. If you feel it answers your question, you can mark it as answer as well

Comment: In your plunker decrease the row height to 20 then see how the data looks in the grid

Comment: From browser dev-tools, set  `.ag-theme-material .ag-cell { line-height: 25px; }` and give it a try. You can change other CSS to make it look more proper